# Conditional SELECT depending on a set of rules

Tags: sql

I need to get data from different columns depending on a set of rules and I don't see how to do it. Let me illustrate this with an example. I have a table:

```
ID   ELEM_01   ELEM_02    ELEM_03
---------------------------------
1     0.12       0          100
2     0.14       5          200
3     0.16       10         300
4     0.18       15         400
5     0.20       20         500
```

And I have a set of rules which look something like this:

> P1Z: ID=2 and ELEM_01
>
> P2Z: ID=4 and ELEM_03
>
> P3Z: ID=4 and ELEM_02
>
> P4Z: ID=3 and ELEM_03

I'm trying to output the following:

```
P1Z    P2Z    P3Z    P4Z
------------------------
0.14   400    15     300
```

I'm used to much simpler queries and this is a bit above my level. I'm getting mixed up by this problem and I don't see a straightforward solution. Any pointers would be appreciated.

**EDIT** Logic behind the rules: the table contains data about different aspects of a piece of equipment. Each combination of ID/ELEM_** represents the value of one aspect of the piece of equipment. The table contains all values of all aspects, but we want a row containing data on only a specific subset of aspects, so that we can output in a single table the values of a specific subset of aspects for all pieces of equipment.

Comment: you'll need to explain the logic used to determine that for ID=2, we want ELEM_01 ... why ? What's the logic behind that ? (explain it in plain English .. and we can convert it to code)

Comment: Why does ID=4 have two two entries P2Z and P3Z where as others don`t?

Comment: This is trivial in a scripting language such as php or Python- don't do it in sql do it in script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each column is numeric and ID is unique you could do:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 2 THEN ELEM_01 END) AS P1Z,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 4 THEN ELEM_03 END) AS P2Z,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 4 THEN ELEM_02 END) AS P3Z,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 3 THEN ELEM_03 END) AS P4Z
...
```

Comment: If you use `MAX` instead of `SUM` it should work for non-numeric data, too.

Comment: True, but using `MAX` with strings always seems icky to me.  Plus, the aggregation is arbitrary - why not use `MIN`?  In that case your data is either invalid or de-normalized (or both).

Comment: I've seen at least one dialect of SQL - SQLite, I think - where NULL is returned as the result of a `MIN`, where both NULL and non-NULL values are included in the dataset. (We don't know which variant of SQL the OP is using.)